# Почему не работает sql запрос?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (wp_postmeta), структура такая:

```
id post_id   key            value
1    11    fromcity_1       Москва
2    11    fromdistrict_1   Садовое кольцо
3    11    fromcity_2       Воронеж
4    11    fromdistrict_1   Коминтерновский
5    13    fromcity_2       Воронеж
6    13    fromdistrict_1   Северный
```

И есть вот такой запрос:

```
 SELECT `post_id`
    FROM `wp_postmeta` AS p
    WHERE p.`key` LIKE 'fromcity_%' AND p.`value` = 'Вороклини'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM wp_postmeta AS c
            WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
                AND c.`key` = concat(`fromdistrict_`, substring(p.`key`, 9))
                AND c.`value` = 'Центр'
        )
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при выполнении запроса, если найдено `fromcity_1`, где "1" это ID, в следующем запросе искать именно `fromdistrict_1`, а не `fromdistrict_2`, `fromdistrict_3` или 4.
Но никак не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепутали кавычки при совмещении строки:

```
AND c.`key` = concat(`fromdistrict_`
```

Получается обозначили строковое значение как имя поля или таблицы.